# Thymeleaf add css styles to html from variable

Tags: thymeleaf

Let's say I have a variable `cssStyles` which contains some **css** as String. I want to send it in my html file in this way

```
<style>
    ${cssStyles}
</style>
```

How can this be achieved with thymeleaf?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the very least you need to mark the style object that you'r using inline thymeleaf and use proper inline syntax. Below a mock of what I think might work.

See https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html#inlining for more information on how to do thymeleaf inlining

```html
<style th:inline="text">
    [(${cssStyles})]
</style>
```